# Why is my Karaf OSGI bundle marked UNSATISFIED, when all references are satisfied?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, apache-karaf

Karaf is showing my bundle as being UNSATISFIED despite all the references being satisfied.

I am using the following three components - relevant console output from scr:list:

```
[20  ] [UNSATISFIED     ] com.barchart.news.modules.mysql.MySQLIndex
[16  ] [ACTIVE          ] com.barchart.news.server.pipeline.StoryPipeline
[14  ] [ACTIVE          ] com.barchart.news.server.common.SharedExecutorProvider
```

Components 16 and 14 provide the following services (output from service:list):

```
service:list com.barchart.news.server.pipeline.PipelineService
[com.barchart.news.server.common.ModuleStatus, com.barchart.news.server.pipeline.PipelineService]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 component.name = com.barchart.news.server.pipeline.StoryPipeline
 component.id = 16
 service.id = 348
Provided by : 
 barchart-news-server (102)

service:list com.barchart.news.server.common.SharedExecutorService 
[com.barchart.news.server.common.ModuleStatus, com.barchart.news.server.common.SharedExecutorService]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 component.name = com.barchart.news.server.common.SharedExecutorProvider
 component.id = 14
 service.id = 346
Provided by : 
 barchart-news-server (102)
Used by: 
 barchart-news-server (102)
```

Within the barchart-news-server bundle that these both are part of, references are satisfied and bound as expected (output from scr:details):

```
scr:details com.barchart.news.server.pipeline.StoryPipeline
Component Details
  Name                : com.barchart.news.server.pipeline.StoryPipeline
  State               : ACTIVE
References
  Reference           : com.barchart.news.server.common.SharedExecutorService/*
    State             : satisfied
    Multiple          : single
    Optional          : mandatory
    Policy            : static
    Service Reference : Bound Service ID 346 (com.barchart.news.server.common.SharedExecutorProvider)
```

However, in the component from the second bundle (#20) that depends on these services, although Karaf marks the references as "satisfied", it does not bind them and activate the component:

scr:details for com.barchart.news.modules.mysql.MySQLIndex:

```
Component Details
  Name                : com.barchart.news.modules.mysql.MySQLIndex
  State               : UNSATISFIED
References
  Reference           : com.barchart.news.server.common.SharedExecutorService/*
    State             : satisfied
    Multiple          : single
    Optional          : mandatory
    Policy            : static
    Service Reference : No Services bound
  Reference           : com.barchart.news.server.pipeline.PipelineService/*
    State             : satisfied
    Multiple          : single
    Optional          : mandatory
    Policy            : static
    Service Reference : No Services bound
```

What is preventing the MySQLIndex bundle from being activated?

Comment: Which version of karaf are you using?

Comment: I asked because it sounds like a bug. Can you try getting a less bleeding edge version? ;)

Comment: Not easily, unfortunately - I was hoping it was something simple I was missing.  One odd thing is that another component with external service dependencies *was* activated OK; the only difference I can see is that its dependencies were release versions, whereas all of mine are 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT right now.  I will try a release and see where that gets me...

Comment: How is the reference declared? Perhaps an obvious question, but do you have a target filter specified?

Comment: Did you try to produce a debug level, showing more details of what might be missing exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read this correctly, then your problem is not an unsatisfied *bundle*, but an unsatisfied *service*. If it so far that the SCR picked up your service, then your bundle must already be active.

With declarative services, I have seen similar behavior when a service with `configuration-policy=require` is missing a configuration. Another possibility is that the `activate`-method threw an exception.

Comment: `policy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE` was my issue. Thanks!